# Refresh token route not returning the user data // Symfony 6, Gesdinet jwtrefreshtoken

Tags: php, symfony, jwt

Currently running an app using gesdinet jwtrefreshtoken.

I have 3 refresh token routes, 2 of them return the correct input which is the token, refreshtoken & user data.

The last one returns only the token and refresh token but is configured the same way the two other ones.

If someone could help figure out what's happening.

routes.yml

```
gesdinet_jwt_refresh_token:
    path:       /{version}/refresh-token
    requirements:
      version: 'v([0-9\.]+)'

gesdinet_jwt_refresh_token_pro:
    path:       /{version}/api-pro/refresh-token
    requirements:
      version: 'v([0-9\.]+)'

gesdinet_jwt_refresh_token_pe:
    path:       /{version}/pe/refresh-token
    requirements:
      version: 'v([0-9\.]+)'
```

security.yml

```
security:
    enable_authenticator_manager: true
    hide_user_not_found: true
    password_hashers:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: auto
        App\Entity\ApiToken:
            algorithm: auto
        App\Entity\PeReferralPsychologist:
            algorithm: auto
        App\Entity\Therapist:
            algorithm: auto

    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        chain_provider:
            chain:
                providers: [app_pro_provider, app_user_provider]
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
        app_pro_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\Therapist
                property: email
        app_pe_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\PeReferralPsychologist
                property: siskaId
        
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            provider: app_user_provider
            security: false
        accountPe:
            pattern: ^/v([0-9\.]+)/pe/(refresh-token)
            provider: app_pe_provider
            stateless: true
            refresh_jwt:
                check_path: gesdinet_jwt_refresh_token_pe
        accountPro:
            pattern:  ^/v([0-9\.]+)/api-pro/(register|refresh-token|forgot-password|validate-reset-token|reset-password)
            provider: app_pro_provider
            stateless: true
            refresh_jwt:
                check_path: gesdinet_jwt_refresh_token_pro
        account:
            pattern:  ^/v([0-9\.]+)/(register|refresh-token|forgot-password|validate-reset-token|reset-password)
            provider: app_user_provider
            stateless: true
            refresh_jwt:
                check_path: gesdinet_jwt_refresh_token
```

Nothing really works, output remains the same with token & refresh token only no user data